# Объясните назначение анонимных функций

Tags: php, callback

недавно начал изучать PHP и встретился с анонимными функциями. Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить в каких ситуация лучше их использовать ? Я так понял, что их используют, чтоб не засорять глобальное пространство. А где они еще могут пригодиться ? Как понять что именно в этом месте нужна анонимная функция ?

Comment: callback-функции.

Comment: Анонимные функции хороши, когда не хочется засорять область видимости.

Comment: в js callback понятно, там асинхронность, но в php то они зачем если весь код выполняется последовательно?

Answer (score 1):

[Документация по анонимным функциям](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php)

Анонимные функции нужны(например) для функций, которые требуют в аргумент функцию обратного вызова, например [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php), [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php), [array_reduce()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reduce.php).

P.S. Все возможности вы найдете в документации, но смысл один: анонимную функцию можно использовать в таких ситуациях, где функция будет использована один раз.

Answer (score 0):

Вот, например, две функции на определение промежутка. По вашему мнению, здесь лучше использовать анонимную функцию ? Или смотреть по обстоятельствам т.е. если функция нужна мне всего один раз, то я буду использовать анонимную функцию. Верно ?

```
function RangeValidator($min, $max){
        return function ($val) use ($min, $max){ // возвращает ф-цию с предустановленными границами
            return ($val >= $min  && $val <= $max) ? true : false;
        };
    }

    $a = getRangeValidator(5, 10);
    echo $a(4);

__________________________________

function RangeValidator($min, $max, $val){
    return ($val >= $min && $val <= $max) ? true : false;
}

echo RangeValidator(5, 10, 4)
```

Хочется разобраться где и когда лучше использовать анонимные функции, а когда нет.